# filter lines starting with ; ussing batch

Tags: text, batch-file, filter, character

Hi I have a script (auto lisp AutoCAD) for a program. The rules of this script are that comments are started with ; character is it possible to write a batch that filters out all lines starting with ;. I namely then encrypt the file from a LSP to a FAS type which renders the commentary as useless (cant be read when encrypted) however AutoCAD still encrypts the text meaning a fairly heavy file size (double of what it should be). The current method is to manually delete every comment line by hand however try doing that a few hundred times. And I need the commentary in place to keep neat record of what’s happening because I work from the not encrypted lisp file its self.

All in all I also want the encryption because its my hard work and my right to keep this secure as it then also means more job security, it also allows me to block some smart alec self proclaimed staff making edditation and in edition the file encryption is recommended for stability reasons by AutoCAD its self.

All in all even if it was because I like to without good reason then that should be valid enough.

I’m looking to achieve this through a batch script as that one of few languages that I feel competent enough in… outside of the AutoCAD frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will convert a file named "source.lsp" and produce "noComment.lsp". It will strip out lines that start with a `;` (including comment lines indented with spaces).

```
findstr /rvc:"^ *;" "source.lsp" >"noComment.lsp"
```

Comment: +1, you are a few seconds faster, with nearly the same answer